# Closed form answer of an Integral containing exponential and cosine function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, special-functions

I am stuck with the following integral while studying some cases of anharmonic Oscillations:

$$\int_0^t\frac{\exp(-\mu t')}{\cos^2(\omega t'-\theta_0)}\, dt'$$

where, $\mu$, $\theta_0$ and $\omega$ have been considered as Real constants.

I have put this integral in Mathematica, which shows a very complicated result involving Hypergeometric functions, but I could not understand how the derivation can be done.

Would you please suggest me any relevant sources or method such that I can do this integral.

Comment: This integral may not have a closed form, but you can proceed with series, but they will also will be quite complex

Comment: @Masd, Thanks for your kind reply...If no closed form is possible, how does Mathematica gives the result, even in the final answer there is some complex term.This is a real integral under real limit, can complexity arise?

Comment: I tried substuting $\cos(\theta)=\frac{(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta})}{2}$, and I got a contour integral, but it'd be pretty difficult to create a contour enclosing every possible singularity, (it changes with variables), but perhaps it might be easier to evaluate to a series?

Comment: @Masd, Thanks again, then taking first few terms of the series 1/ cos^2 x would be easier...If you kindly post something in this regard....approximated result may suffice the purpose, if it satisfies the physical situation

Answer (score 1):

Let $ u =  wt'-\theta_0 \Rightarrow dt' = \frac{du}{w} $, $ t' = \frac{(u+\theta_0)}{w}$ $a = w\times0-\theta_0$ and $b=wt-\theta_0$
Also set $\psi  = \frac\mu{w}$
$$ w^{-1}\int_a^b e^{-\psi(u+\theta_0)}\sec^2(u)du=w^{-1}e^{-\psi\theta_0}\int_a^b e^{-\psi u}\sec^2(u)du=w^{-1}e^{-\psi\theta_0}\left(\left.e^{-\psi u}\tan{(u)}\right.\rvert_a^b+\psi\int_a^b e^{-\psi u}\tan{(u)} du\right)$$

Now to evaluate
$$
\int_a^b e^{-\psi u}\tan{(u)} du
$$
Set $
\xi = e^{-\psi u} \Rightarrow du =  -\psi e^{\psi u} d\xi
$ and $u = \frac{-\ln(r)}{\psi}$
So
$c=e^{-\psi a}$ $ d =e^{-\psi b}$
$$
\int_a^b e^{-\psi u}\tan{(u)} du=\psi\int_c^d \tan{\left(\frac{\ln(\xi)}{\psi}\right)} d\xi=\psi i^{-1}\int_c^d \frac{e^{\frac{\ln(\xi)i}{\psi}}-e^{-\frac{\ln(\xi)i}{\psi}}}{e^{\frac{-\ln(\xi)i}{\psi}}+e^{\frac{\ln(\xi)i}{\psi}}} d\xi=\psi i^{-1}\left(\xi\rvert_c^d-2\int_c^d \frac{e^{-\frac{\ln(\xi)i}{\psi}}}{e^{\frac{-\ln(\xi)i}{\psi}}+e^{\frac{\ln(\xi)i}{\psi}}} d\xi\right)=\psi i^{-1}\left(\xi\rvert_c^d-2\int_c^d \frac{1}{(e^{\frac{-\ln(\xi)i}{\psi}}+e^{\frac{\ln(\xi)i}{\psi}})e^{\frac{\ln(\xi)i}{\psi}}} d\xi\right)=\psi i^{-1}\left(\xi\rvert_c^d-2\int_c^d \frac{1}{(1+e^{\frac{2\ln(\xi)i}{\psi}})} d\xi\right)=\psi i^{-1}\left(\xi\rvert_c^d-2\int_c^d \frac{1}{(1+\xi^{\frac{2i}{\psi}})} d\xi\right)
$$
Overall
$$
w^{-1}e^{-\psi\theta_0}\left(\left.e^{-\psi u}\tan{(u)}\right.\rvert_a^b+\psi^2i^{-1}\left(\xi\rvert_c^d-2\int_c^d \frac{1}{(1+\xi^{\frac{2i}{\psi}})} d\xi\right)\right)
$$